# Pandas dataframe, grouping 3 columns and counting the third

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to group a dataframe by 3 columns, date, time and article, and return an object where i have the groups of date, time and article, and the count of each article per time (hour).

This code does the trick with the grouping, but I can't figure out how to also get the count:

```
dfs.groupby([dfs['Dato'].dt.date,dfs['Tid'].dt.hour,dfs['Varenavn']])
```

so this could be my input:

```
01.01.2018   0901  Car
01.01.2018   0905  Car
01.01.2018   0945  Horse
01.01.2018   1005  Car
02.01.2018   0900  Horse
02.01.2018   0915  Horse
02.01.2018   1050  Car
02.01.2018   1055  Horse
```

Wanted output:

```
01.01.2018 09-10 Car   2
                 Horse 1
01.01.2018 10-11 Car   1
02.01.2018 09-10 Horse 2 
02.01.2018 10-11 Car   1 
                 Horse 1
```

My overall goal is to find how many items were sold per hour per day, from a dataframe containing every sold item, at what time and at what date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + df['time'].astype(str), format='%m.%d.%Y%H%M')
grouper = df.datetime.dt.strftime('%m.%d.%Y %H-') + (df.datetime.dt.hour+1).astype(str)
dfout = df.groupby(grouper)['article'].value_counts().to_frame('count')
```

---

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
      date  time article
01.01.2018   901     Car
01.01.2018   905     Car
01.01.2018   945   Horse
01.01.2018  1005     Car
02.01.2018   900   Horse
02.01.2018   915   Horse
02.01.2018  1050     Car
02.01.2018  1055   Horse'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj, sep='\s+')

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + df['time'].astype(str), format='%m.%d.%Y%H%M')
grouper = df.datetime.dt.strftime('%m.%d.%Y %H-') + (df.datetime.dt.hour+1).astype(str)
dfout = df.groupby(grouper)['article'].value_counts().to_frame('count')
print(dfout)
```

Returns:

```
                            count
datetime         article         
01.01.2018 09-10 Car            2
                 Horse          1
01.01.2018 10-11 Car            1
02.01.2018 09-10 Horse          2
02.01.2018 10-11 Car            1
                 Horse          1
```

Comment: thx! this worked, but i had to add .astype(str) to df['date'] to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming columns `Dato`, `Tid`, and `Varenavn` in your OG dataframe, try this:

```
df['datetime'] = df['Dato'] + str(' ') + df['Tid']
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format = '%m.%d.%Y %H%M')
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key = 'datetime', freq = 'H'), 'Varenavn'])['Varenavn'].count()
```

OUTPUT:

```
datetime             Varenavn  
2018-01-01 09:00:00  Car      2
                     Horse    1
2018-01-01 10:00:00  Car      1
2018-02-01 09:00:00  Horse    2
2018-02-01 10:00:00  Car      1
                     Horse    1
```

...implicitly assuming that the hour in the timestamp is the start-time. You can reindex and play with the datetime to get the desired format.